# IFeatureWorkspace.CreateFeatureClass() error

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.0, c#, esri-geodatabase

I am trying to read a csv file straight into a set of new feature classes within a new file geodatabase, but I am getting the following stack trace when it fails:

> Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication
>   that other memory is corrupt.
>   ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase at
>   ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureDataset.CreateFeatureClass(String
>   Name, IFields Fields, UID CLSID, UID
>   EXTCLSID, esriFeatureType FeatureType,
>   String ShapeFieldName, String
>   ConfigKeyword) at
>   WaterEditorExtension.Model.SurveyUtilities.StreamWriting(String
>   pointtype, String outfile, String[]
>   record, IWorkspace workspace) in
>   C:\Documents and Settings\lbadgerow\My
>   Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\WaterEditorExtension\WaterEditorExtension\Model\SurveyUtilities.cs:line
>   206.

I believe that it is related to a schema lock, but I am able to create a feature dataset which is confusing.  (In proper stacktrace form, below is my workspace factory call, and my where I'm building the FC)

```
        public IWorkspace CreateFileGdbWorkspace(String path, String jobnumber)
        {
            Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory");
            IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType);

            IWorkspaceName workspaceName = workspaceFactory.Create(path, jobnumber, null, 0);

            IName name = (IName)workspaceName;
            IWorkspace workspace = (IWorkspace)name.Open();
            return workspace;
        }
...
IFeatureWorkspace featwork = (IFeatureWorkspace)workspace;
featwork.CreateFeatureClass("test", outfields, CLSID, null, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, "SHAPE", "");
```

EDIT 17 March 2011:  has anyone attempted to Thread a component (extension) of ArcMap?  I'm thinking that I could release the schema lock that is preventing this from moving on to the FC creation phase of this project, but I can't seem to get ArcMap to remain stable when I create a new thread to build the gdb.

Comment: I had some issues that where solved by making sure that garbage collection don't remove objects that are sharing state between COM object. You could try making some of the variables static and release those after you finishing the whole operation?

Comment: Thanks Mathias.  I've actually got CreateFileGDBWorkspace() set as a static method now, but it's giving me the same respone.  I went so far as to "slum it" and tried creating a shapefileworkspacefactory but got the same results, I got as far as throwing a COMException yesterday but I was trying to rule out the chance that I was passing invalid fields (using IFieldChecker)

Comment: UPDATE: I'm building the geodatabase in a background thread now, and when I reclaim that thread I am without a lock on the geodatabase, however I'm still having the issue when I use the wsfactory to open the gdb so that I can create the new fc's

Comment: UPDATE: It's looking like there is a flaw in the .NET framework around the IList<T> and ICollection<T> that causes the excption in my case.  I was able to create a workflow with python that takes care of the data creation and import.  The only hitch is that you have to call the python script as a new Process() from within the application.  email me if you are interested in the code/ workaround.  good luck

Comment: @Luke: Could you describe how `IList<T>` and `ICollection<T>` supposedly lead to your issue? While I believe it highly unlikely that these .NET Framework interfaces or the implementing classes are broken in any way (since they are so crucial and thus very well-tested), if indeed they cause problems during COM interop, it would be extremely helpful to know about it!

Comment: @stakx:  it ended up being a non-issue, we gave up on threading (it's been so long now and I'm off that project), as I look at what's in source control.

But you are correct,  The DOTNET Framework interfaces were 

Rather than use the Type class, I instantiate a new UIDClass and set the value property to esriGeodatabase.Feature

Answer (score 2):

This error occur when the field count is not matched to created fields.

```
    Dim fields As IFields = New FieldsClass
    Dim fieldsEdit As IFieldsEdit = CType(fields, IFieldsEdit)
    fieldsEdit.FieldCount_2 = 2

    ' Create Object ID field.
    Dim fieldUserDefined As IField = New Field

    Dim fieldEdit As IFieldEdit = CType(fieldUserDefined, IFieldEdit)
    fieldEdit.Name_2 = "OBJECTID"
    fieldEdit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeOID
    fieldsEdit.Field_2(0) = fieldUserDefined

    ' Create Shape field.
    fieldUserDefined = New Field
    fieldEdit = CType(fieldUserDefined, IFieldEdit)

    ' Set up geometry definition for the Shape field.
    ' You do not have to set the spatial reference, as it is inherited from the feature dataset.
    Dim geometryDef As IGeometryDef = New GeometryDefClass
    Dim geometryDefEdit As IGeometryDefEdit = CType(geometryDef, IGeometryDefEdit)

    ' By setting the grid size to 0, you are allowing ArcGIS to determine the appropriate grid sizes for the feature class. 
    ' If in a personal geodatabase, the grid size is 1,000. If in a file or ArcSDE geodatabase, the grid size
    ' is based on the initial loading or inserting of features.
    geometryDefEdit.GeometryType_2 = ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon
    geometryDefEdit.GridCount_2 = 1
    'geometryDefEdit.GridSize(0, 0)
    geometryDefEdit.HasM_2 = True
    geometryDefEdit.HasZ_2 = False
    ' Set standard field properties.
    fieldEdit.Name_2 = "SHAPE"
    fieldEdit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGeometry

    fieldEdit.GeometryDef_2 = geometryDef
    fieldEdit.IsNullable_2 = True
    fieldEdit.Required_2 = True
    fieldsEdit.Field_2(1) = fieldUserDefined

    ' Create a field of type double to hold some information for the features.
    fieldUserDefined = New Field

    fieldEdit = CType(fieldUserDefined, IFieldEdit)


    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '--------------------------------- CREATE FEATURE CLASS------------------------------------------
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Create a feature class description object to use for specifying the CLSID and EXTCLSID.
    Dim fcDesc As IFeatureClassDescription = New FeatureClassDescriptionClass
    Dim ocDesc As IObjectClassDescription = CType(fcDesc, IObjectClassDescription)
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim pWorkspaceFactory As IWorkspaceFactory = New SdeWorkspaceFactory
```

if fieldEdit.FieldCount is equal to a number greater than 2 , this error will occur.